# Octave 4.0.0 Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, octave

trying to install GNU Octave on Ubuntu 14.04. I've tried following the solution in [this almost identical question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670387/gnu-octave-wont-install-because-of-package-conflicts)  and ran the command `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` , but I still get the same list of errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

octave: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
    Depends: libglpk36 (>= 4.51) but 4.52.1-2build1 is to be installed
    Depends: liboctave3 (= 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1) but 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1 is to be installed
    Depends: libgl1-mesa-glide3 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libportaudio2 (>= 19+svn20101113) but 19+svn20140130-1 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
    Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
    Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
    Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
    Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
    Depends: octave-common (= 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1) but 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1 is to be installed
```

Does that mean I need to run `sudo apt-get install <package>` to every one of the packages that are listed in the error detail?

Thanks

This is the output of `apt-cache policy octave libgcc1` :

```
octave:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1
  Version table:
     4.0.0-3ubuntu2~octave~trusty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     3.8.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libgcc1:
  Installed: 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Try `apt-get install -f` and see what happens.

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670797/unable-to-install-octave/670800#670800)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy octave libgcc1`

Comment: @A.B. Added to the

Comment: @ThomasW. , I've tried it before posting the question.

Comment: I tried using the proposed  solution:`sudo apt-get build-dep octave` and then installing octave from the software centre, is that what you mean @Ravan? otherwise I don't know how to apply the reference to my case.

Comment: This is totally illogical: `octave: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed`. o_O

Comment: I mean look at the answer by @A.B you may get some idea. (which is answer to that provided link) not mine. (I want to give link to that question)

Comment: @psithetazhe: do you have the LTS [hardware enablement](http://askubuntu.com/q/248914/70254) packages installed on your system? If so, there is a (known, at least to me, PPA maintainer) incompatibility that may explain this error.

Comment: And after following @Ravan's link to a similar [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/670984/70254) it does look to me like the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the intermittent response @MikeMiller Thanks for the comments, I did try to follo @Ravan's link, including the linked archived chat, but, I couldn't get it working. I've installed  `linux-hwe-generic-trusty` as well. Would you mind getting on chat to help me resolve it?

Comment: @psithetazhe: I have updated the PPA package so it should be installable now. The underlying bug is still present, but I have rebuilt Octave so it does not depend on OSMesa for now until [#1424059](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1424059) is fixed.

Comment: @MikeMiller, thanks a lot! that works! got Octave 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 installed.